# Can't use constructors in other classes Android (Java)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a List View, with each list element having 3 textviews.

Here are the declared values in MainActivity.java

```
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
```

In the onCreate function

I have the following code:

```
listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        String []elemnt1 = {"1", "2", "3"};
        String []elemnt2 = {"3", "4", "5"};
        String []elemnt3 = {"6", "7", "8"};

        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i=0;i<elemnt1.length;i++){
            arraylist.add((new Element(elemnt2[i],elemmnt2[i],elemnt3[i])));
        }
```

I get the error in the 2nd last line

```
arraylist.add((new Element(elemnt2[i],elemmnt2[i],elemnt3[i])));
```

The error is
`dataList.add((new Ride(dates[i],times[i],distances[i])));`

My Element class is pretty simple, a constructor and getters:

```
public class Element {
    private String fire;
    private String earth;
    private String water;


    public Element(String fire, String earth, String water) {
        this.fire = fire;
        this.earth = earth;
        this.water = water;
    }

    public String getFire() {
        return this.fire;
    }

    public String getEarth() {
        return this.Earth;
    }

    public String getWater() {
        return this.Water;
    }
}
```

What could be causing the issue?

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: Include the error that you receive in the post

Comment: `public Ride(String fire, String earth, String water)`  this somehow looks like a constructor (has no return type) but it's name doesn't match the class name (`Element`).

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList<String>` reads as *a list of `String` type objects*. So problably `ArrayList<Element>` is whay you're looging for.

That's why you get an error when you trying to `add()` objects of type `Element` in a list of `String`s.

Also your constructor must match the class name, so change it to `Element()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Element> arrayList;
```

give same name of constructor and class

```
public class Element {
    private String fire;
    private String earth;
    private String water;


    public Element(String fire, String earth, String water) {
        this.fire = fire;
        this.earth = earth;
        this.water = water;
    }

    public String getFire() {
        return this.fire;
    }

    public String getEarth() {
        return this.Earth;
    }

    public String getWater() {
        return this.Water;
    }
}
```